# Shortcut to jump to last non-empty row in range skipping empty rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I jump from one cell in a column to the last non-empty cell in that column whereas there are empty cells in between?

Example:
Here I want to use a shortcut to jump from Cell 1 to Cell 5.
(Ctrl + arrow down is not working, because it will stop at Cell 2.)

```
Column A
Cell 1 with value
Cell 2 with value
_empty cell_
Cell 3 with value
_empty cell_
Cell 4 with value
Cell 5 with value
```

Comment: Ctrl + End will go to the last non empty Cell

Comment: Most of the time, Ctrl + down is very quick. However, if your spreadsheet has many blank cells in the particular column, you'll need to continue pressing the hotkey to skip the blank cells. In that case, Ctrl + End is best. But it will take to the last cell used (last row, last column ) in the file

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above in comments, <kbd>CTRL+END</kbd> will take you to the last cell in the worksheet.

If you want to go to the last cell in a column, AFAIK, you may need a macro as (which you noticed) <kbd>CTRL+DOWN</kbd> will stop at the first empty cell.

Put this macro in a module in your workbook, and you can then assign a keyboard shortcut to it and it'll select the last non-empty cell in the active column.

```
Sub gotoLastRow()
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Select
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1:

Your quickest way, though it's still two steps, would be to use the `Name Box` or `Go To` to jump to the last cell in the column you're interested in, then use <kbd>Ctrl+Up.</kbd>

Assuming we wanted to find the last used cell in column A, you could click in the `Name Box` and enter `A65536` (if you're in compatibility mode) or `A1048576` (if you're not), then hit Enter. That will jump you to the end of the sheet. You can then use <kbd>Ctrl+Up</kbd> as normal to find the last actually used cell.

If you know roughly how long your data is, though, you don't need to use row 65536 or row 1048576 - any row that you KNOW is beyond the end of your data would work.

### 2:

It may be simpler, though it's still an extra couple of key presses, to use the <kbd>Ctrl+End</kbd> method suggested in other answers. The downside to this is that you need to navigate back to the column you actually want, which of course may or may not extend all the way down to the end of your data.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the column header label to highlight the column. (Notice the selected cell will be the row 1 cell for the column, just under the column header label.)
2. Press `Shift-TAB` to "move up a cell" in the column. Like with video games of yore, going off screen at the top will bring you back on screen at the bottom. You now have the last cell in the column (row 65536 or 1048576) selected.
3. Press your choice of methods for moving up the column to the last used cell above the one you have selected. I use `End-Up Arrow` and sometimes `Ctrl-Up Arrow`, but there are likely others as well.
4. Since you were in the absolutely last cell in the column, by definition the last cell used above the one you are in is the last used cell in the column.

Done.

No `Ctrl-End` and then wobbling about to the correct column or other chance-of-error type wandering around. One set of a couple key presses, always in the desired column.

(As to finding such in the (unknown) column that has the lowest used cell, `Ctrl-End` puts you on its row, then `End-Left Arrow` or `Ctrl-Left Arrow` takes you right to the lowest used cell in any column at all.)

To get really wild, and not use the mouse at all, arrow your way into the column, then press `Ctrl-Space Bar` to select the column. Press `Ctrl-.` ("Control-Period") to move to the row one cell. Press it again to move to the last row's cell. (If already in row 1, only one pressing is needed.) Then up to the last used cell with `End-Up Arrow`.

And to go REALLY crazy, highlight the column using `Ctrl-Space Bar` from whatever cell in the column you are in, avoiding that being row 1's cell. Then press `Ctrl-|` (or as some would prefer to write that, `Ctrl-Shift-|`) (it is the "pipe symbol" above the backslash key).

All, and ONLY, the used cells (non-true-blank cells), even ones that result in "", will be selected and the row 1 cell will be the working cell. Pressing `Shift-TAB` will now "roll around" to the LAST of those used cells. Directly to it.

(I was particular to say not row 1's cell because the key combo works slightly differently then. Noticeably differently! Not like it causes a tsunami, but it does act differently enough it is not helpful in this task.)

Answer (score 0):

###### Keyboard Shortcut

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> *then* <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> *then* <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

###### Fastest Way

Hold down the <kbd>Control</kbd> key continuously during the sequence, releasing it only at the end.

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: This is an old question and CTRL+END has already been cited in the other answers, even that it may be faster.  The reason the answers don't match yours is that the OP in't looking for the last populated row.  The are looking for the last populated row **in a range** which could be in column  75 of 127 columns.  You should consider only answering old questions if they haven't been well answered of you have something substantial to add. Please [edit] to reflect the question at least.